# Explain the deviousness of the Perl "preamble"

Tags: perl, shell, csh

The Perl manual describes a *totally devious construct that will work under any of csh, sh, or Perl, such as the following*:

```
eval '(exit $?0)' && eval 'exec perl -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    & eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -wS $0 $argv:q'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
```

Devious indeed... can someone please explain in detail how this works?

Comment: For an even hackier preamble that works as Perl or HTML, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406711/make-my-file-readable-as-either-perl-or-html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The idea is that those three lines do 3 different things if they're evaluated in a standard Bourne shell (sh), a C shell (csh), or Perl.  This hack is only needed on systems that don't support specifying an interpreter name using a `#!` line at the start of a script.  If you execute a Perl script beginning with those 3 lines as a shell script, the shell will launch the Perl interpreter, passing it the script's filename and the command line arguments.

In Perl, the three lines form one statement, terminated by the `;`, of the form

```
eval '...' && eval '...' & eval '...' if $running_under_some_shell;
```

Since the script just started, `$running_under_some_shell` is `undef`, which is false, and the evals are never executed.  It's a no-op.

The devious part is that `$?0` is parsed differently in sh versus csh.  In sh, that means `$?` (the exit status of the last command) followed by 0.  Since there is no previous command, `$?` will be 0, so `$?0` evaluates to `00`.  In csh, `$?0` is a special variable that is 1 if the current input filename is known, or 0 if it isn't.  Since the shell is reading these lines from a script, `$?0` will be 1.

Therefore, in sh, `eval '(exit $?0)'` means `eval '(exit 00)'`, and in csh it means `eval '(exit 1)'`.  The parens indicate that the exit command should be evaluated in a subshell.

Both sh and csh understand `&&` to mean "execute the previous command, then execute the following command only if the previous command exited 0".  So only sh will execute `eval 'exec perl -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'`.  csh will proceed to the next line.

csh will ignore "& " at the beginning of a line.  (I'm not sure exactly what that means to csh.  Its purpose is to make this a single expression from Perl's point of view.)  csh then proceeds to evaluate `eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -wS $0 $argv:q'`.

These two command lines are quite similar.  `exec perl` means to replace the current process by launching a copy of `perl`.  `-wS` means the same as `-w` (enable warnings) and `-S` (look for the specified script in `$PATH`).  `$0` is the filename of the script.  Finally both `${1+"$@"}` and `$argv:q` produce a copy of the current command line arguments (in sh and csh, respectively).

It uses `${1+"$@"}` instead of the more usual `"$@"` to work around a bug in some ancient version of the Bourne shell.  They mean the same thing.  You can read the details in [Bennett Todd's explanation](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/sh_dollar_at) (copied in gbacon's answer).

Comment: @cjm Won't the -w switch cause a warning to be issued because $running_under_some_shell is used before it's defined?

Comment: Also... does anyone know what the & at the beginning of the line means for csh?

Comment: @JoelFan: No, `-w` is not the same as `use strict`.  Using `undef` in a Boolean condition doesn't cause a warning.  And even if the script did `use strict`, that's lexically scoped, and the preamble would come before that line, so strictness wouldn't apply.

Comment: FYI... I asked the ampersand question separately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314726/ampersand-at-beginning-of-a-line-in-csh

Answer (score 10):

From Tom Christiansen's collection [Far More Than Everything You've Ever Wanted to Know About …](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/index.html):

#### [Why we use `eval 'exec perl $0 -S ${1+"$@"}'`](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/sh_dollar_at)

> Newsgroups: comp.lang.tcl,comp.unix.shell
>   From: bet@ritz.mordor.com (Bennett Todd)
>   Subject: Re: `"$@"` versus `${1+"$@"}`
>   Followup-To: comp.unix.shell
>   Date: Tue, 26 Sep 1995 14:35:45 GMT
>   Message-ID: <DFIoJL.934@ritz.mordor.com>
>
> (This isn't really a TCL question; it's a Bourne Shell question; so I've
>   cross-posted, and set followups, to comp.unix.shell).
>
> Once upon a time (or so the story goes) there was a Bourne Shell somewhere
>   which offered two choices for interpolating the whole command-line. The
>   simplest was `$*`, which just borfed in all the args, losing any quoting that
>   had protected internal whitespace. It also offered `"$@"`, to protect
>   whitespace. Now the icko bit is how `"$@"` was implemented. In this early
>   shell, the two-character sequence `$@` would interpolate as
>
> ```
> $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" ... $n
> ```
>
> so that when you added the surrounding quotes, it finished quoting the whole
>   schmeer. Cute, cute, too cute.... Now consider what the correct usage
>
> ```
> "$@"
> ```
>
> will expand to *if there are no args*:
>
> ```
> ""
> ```
>
> That's the empty string — a single argument of length zero. That's *not*
>   the same as no args at all. So, someone came up with a clever application of
>   another Bourne Shell feature, conditional interpolation. The idiom
>
> ```
> ${varname+value}
> ```
>
> expands to `value` if `varname` is set, and nothing otherwise. Thus the
>   idiom under discussion
>
> ```
> ${1+"$@"}
> ```
>
> means exactly, precisely the same as a simple
>
> ```
> "$@"
> ```
>
> without that ancient, extremely weird bug.
>
> So now the question: what shells *had* that bug? Are there any shells
>   shipped with any even vaguely recent OS that included it?
>
> ```
> -- 
> -Bennett
> bet@mordor.com
> http://www.mordor.com/bet/
> ```