# ampersand at beginning of a line in csh

Tags: linux, unix, shell, csh

What does an ampersand at the **beginning** of a line do in csh?  It seems to be ignored (with no error message), but why?

Comment: show a full example of that line.

Comment: We're trying to fill in a detail for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308874/explain-the-deviousness-of-the-perl-preamble

Answer (score 4):

Found something interesting:

> The semicolon (;) character separates
>   successive commands on a single
>   command line. For example,

```
% <command1> ; <command2>
```

> executes <command1>, and when it finishes, <command2> gets executed.
>
> The ampersand character (&) is similar
>   to the semicolon (;) but does not wait
>   for <command1> to finish.

Maybe it's treating it like an empty command?

Comment: In Bourne shell, if you start a command line with semi-colon, you get a syntax error; ditto for ampersand.  However, if csh treats it as an empty command run in background, it at least makes sense (of a sort).  (And csh allows both "`; echo abc`" and "`& echo abc`", echoing 'abc' in each case - consistent with the empty command hypothesis).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer will be example.
Taking idea of JoelFAn ahaed:

**EXAMPLE 1**

> **user$ date ; sleep 5s ; date**
>
> Thu Apr  5 10:46:45 IST 2012
>
> Thu Apr  5 10:46:50 IST 2012

**EXAMPLE 2**

> **user$ date & sleep 5s & date**
>
> [1] 18371
>
> [2] 18372
>
> Thu Apr  5 10:47:09 IST 2012
>
> Thu Apr  5 10:47:09 IST 2012
>
> [1]  - Done                          date

**EXAMPLE3**

> **user$ bg**
>
> [2]    sleep 5s &

The examples are self explanatory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything in csh docs about it. However, I know in [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) it suppresses any output from the command (but still runs it). Perhaps that's what it is doing.

Comment: In which version of 'make' does '&' suppress the output from the command?  I know of '@' to stop 'make' echoing the command; I know of '-' to stop 'make' paying attention to a non-zero exit status.