# make my file readable as either Perl or HTML

Tags: html, perl, comments

In the spirit of the "[Perl Preamble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308874/explain-the-deviousness-of-the-perl-preamble)" where a script works properly whether executed by a shell script interpreter or the Perl interpreter...

I have a Perl script which contains an embedded HTML document (as a "heredoc"), i.e.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

... some Perl code ...

my $html = <<'END' ;
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>

... more HTML ...

</HTML>
END

... Perl code that processes $html ...
```

I would like to be able to work on the HTML that's inside the Perl script and check it out using a web browser, and only run the script when the HTML is the way I want.  To accomplish this, I need the file to be openable both as an HTML file and as a Perl script.

I have tried various tricks with Perl comments and HTML comments but can't get it quite perfect.  The file as a whole doesn't have to be "strictly legal" HTML (although the embedded document should be)... just displayable in a browser with no (or minimal) Perl garbage visible.

**EDIT:** Solved!  See my own answer

Comment: I think your solution set is the empty set. If you intend to associate perl with the file by a shbang then you need the first line. An SGML comment cannot occur before this line, so you're going to show the shbang--and most browsers will put it as it's own document--even if it makes non-standard HTML.

Comment: Just add some Javascript to remove the shebang from the DOM!

Comment: @Axeman, see empty set below ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read it and weep Mr. @Axeman... I now present to you **the empty set**:

```
</dev/fd/0 eval 'exec perl -x -S $0 ${1+"$@"}' #> <!--
#!perl

... some Perl code ...

my $html = << '<!-- END' ;  # -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>

... more HTML ...

</HTML>
<!-- END

... Perl code that processes $html ...

# -->
```

Comment: Neat trick. Although I would still advise against it. You should really have separate things in separate places.

Comment: I commend you on your cleverness.

Comment: +1 for awesome hackishness.  But, for production code or any other circumstance where maintainability is even a minor concern, I still maintain that using templates (as suggested in the answer I submitted yesterday) will cause you far less pain in the long run.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a path to pain. Consider storing the HTML in a separate file and reading it in within the script.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is a job for [`Markup::Perl`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Markup::Perl):

```
  # don't write this...
  print "Content-type: text/html;\n\n";
  print "<html>\n<body>\n";
  print "<p>\nYour \"lucky number\" is\n";
  print "<i>", int rand 10, "</i>\n</p>\n";
  print "</body>\n</html>\n";

  # write this instead...
  use Markup::Perl;
  <html><body><p>
  Your "lucky number" is
  <i><perl> print int rand 10 </perl></i>
  </p></body></html>
```

You could also drop the `use Markup::Perl` line and run your script like

```
perl -MMarkup::Perl my_page_with_embedded_perl.html
```

Then the page should render pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you want a templating solution, such as [Template::Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template) or [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Template).  Embedding HTML in your code or embedding code in your HTML is a recipe for pain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting Perl **inside** of HTML?

Like [ASP4](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ASP4) does?

It's a **lot** easier that way - trust me ;-)

Comment: Clearly Template::Refine is the best approach ;)

Comment: Interesting... no ... **awesome**!