# What is the exact meaning of the find2perl perl shebang + eval?

Tags: perl, eval

What exacly do the following?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
    eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
        if 0; #$running_under_some_shell
```

- the `if 0` is never true, so the eval part will never executed,
- and the eval is strange too - what is the value of `$0` in this context (inside single quotes?)

Ps: taken from the result of the find2perl command

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308874/explain-the-deviousness-of-the-perl-preamble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best guess - as in this comment `#$running_under_some_shell`, it's to detect if the script is being run by some shell other than perl, e.g. bash.

> the if 0 is never true, so the eval part will never executed,

Not by perl, no. By other shells such as bash it won't spot the line continuation and will just execute the `eval` statement. This then re-runs the script under perl. (Oddly with different options than the hashbang line.)

> and the eval is strange too - what is the value of $0 in this context (inside single quotes?)

Again, this will be expanded by bash not perl: here it means the path to find2perl to pass into the perl interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

I found some discussion here:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=825147

> The extended hashbang is there so you
>   can run your Perl script with almost
>   any /bin/sh under the sun, even a
>   shell/kernel that does not honor the
>   hashbang and it will still launch perl
>   in the end.