# Understanding a code chunk of perl

Tags: perl

Can anyone explain to me what the following is trying to do? What is the purpose behind this code chunk?

```
#!/bin/perl
eval 'exec perl5 -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
   if 0;
```

Thanks much!

**EDIT1:** I'm trying to change the code block above into:

```
#!/bin/sh
eval 'exec perl5 -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
   if 0;
```

and I think it should work because the script is treated like shell script and `eval` get executed and `perl5` is invoked to use perl to execute the same script. However, when I actually run this, I got:

`/bin/sh: -S: invalid option`

Can anyone explain why this case the script is failed. Do I misunderstand something? I'm using `ksh`

Thanks much!

**EDIT2:** EDIT1 seems like a totally separate question and I post it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422715/a-change-of-shebang-eval-leads-to-the-perl-script-failure)

Comment: Simply searching for this phrase gives lots of hits, among them [What is the exact meaning of the find2perl perl shebang + eval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123971/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-the-find2perl-perl-shebang-eval). And this should answer your question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the link!

Comment: Did this code come from `find2perl`?

Comment: @Borodin Nope but they look quite similar: ``eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
        if 0; #$running_under_some_shell``

Comment: @Jerry: Yeah, I guess it's been stolen. It's a hack, basically. I've written a skeleton answer below that should help.

Comment: You just amended your OP and added another question. Please post a new question instead.

Comment: @PerlDog Done. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422715/a-change-of-shebang-eval-leads-to-the-perl-script-failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dirty trick to get a script file to run either properly, under perl, or if it is submitted directly to the shell

The statement does absolutely nothing under perl because of the `if 0` at the end

However, if it's executed by sh or bash then the continuation line will be ignored, and the shell will do the `eval`, and run the same file through `perl5`

The idea is that, while Perl considers newlines as just more whitespace, the shell sees them as statement terminators. That means Perl will ignore the `eval` (as long as it compiles) because the rest of the statement says `if 0`, while a shell will execute it and `exec` to a whole new process

I can't say I see the point, because a proper shebang line will allow you to run `foo.pl` directly from the command line anyway, but there we are. People like hacks because it makes them feel clever

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the intuition behind this code chunk now: basically I can either run ``perl foo`` or ``foo`` directly in shell. But, could you elaborate more on "because of ``if 0 at the end``" and "the continuation line"? I'm really new to perl. Thanks much for the help!

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123971/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-the-find2perl-perl-shebang-eval and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68484/what-does-1-mean-in-a-shell-script-and-how-does-it-differ-from make sense the most to me. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Jerry: The idea is that, while Perl considers newlines as just more whitespace, the shell sees them as statement terminators. That means Perl will ignore the `eval` because the rest of the statement says `if 0`, while a shell will execute it and `exec` to a whole new process. I can't say I see the point, because a proper shebang line will allow you to run `foo.pl` directly from the command line anyway, but there we are. People like hacks because it makes them feel clever.

Comment: so what is really the point of ``eval`` part? Is it just for people to avoid a weird bug coming from very old borne-shell? Or it is for people want to execute the desire perl from ``$PATH`` instead of default system perl? Or maybe both? Thanks!

Comment: @Jerry: That's only to allow the statement to compile under Perl, even though it will never be executed. Please don't dwell on this, and use it as an example of something to avoid, if at all. Consider your current confusion, and try to avoid anyone else suffering in the same way.