# A change of shebang + eval leads to the perl script failure

Tags: perl, shell

This is a question derives from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421103/understanding-a-code-chunk-of-perl?). Based upon the comments and answer from that post, I change the following shebang + eval into another one:

**Old works version**

```
#!/bin/perl
eval 'exec perl5 -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
   if 0;
```

**New doesn't work version**

```
#!/bin/sh
eval 'exec perl5 -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
   if 0;
```

Notice that I change `#!/bin/perl` to `#!/bin/sh` and based upon my understanding, the new version should also work because the script is treated like shell script and `eval` get executed and `perl5` is invoked to use perl to execute the same script. However, when I actually run this, I got:

```
/bin/sh: -S: invalid option
```

Can anyone explain why this case the script is failed. Do I misunderstand something? I'm using `ksh`

Also this [web page](https://perlbrew.pl/Dealing-with-shebangs.html) I found online seems suggest that my new version should work as well.

Thanks much!

Comment: show  your sample execution, are there any arg values for `$1` or `$@` ? And did you try `#!/bin/ksh` ? Good luck.

Comment: This question is exploring arcane and inadvisable corners of shell and perl

Comment: @Borodin True (I actually prefer `#!/usr/bin/env perl` and never had problems; I think you do it the same way), but it's an interesting question nevertheless. I thought it's not the shell's business to interpret the `-S` switch as it's a parameter to `perl5`. So why does the _shell_ complain?

Comment: Btw: This behaviour is not restricted to `ksh` (which is the standard shell in AIX), but also applies to `bash`. I also got `/bin/bash: -S: invalid option` (no matter how many parameters I called the script with).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Perl documentation:

> If the `#!` line does not contain the word "perl" nor the word "indir", the program named after the `#!` is executed instead of the Perl interpreter. This is slightly bizarre, but it helps people on machines that don't do `#!`, because they can tell a program that their SHELL is */usr/bin/perl*, and Perl will then dispatch the program to the correct interpreter for them.

So if you launch the modified version as `./script`:

1. Your shell executes `./script`
2. The kernel actually executes `/bin/sh ./script`
3. `sh` executes `perl5 -S ./script`
4. `perl5` executes `/bin/sh -S ./script` because it sees a shebang that doesn't contain `perl`.
5. `sh` dies because it doesn't recognize the `-S` option.

And if you launch the modified version as `perl5 script`:

1. Your shell executes `perl5 script`
2. `perl5` executes `/bin/sh -S script` because it sees a shebang that doesn't contain `perl`.
3. `sh` dies because it doesn't recognize the `-S` option.

> *Also this web page I found online seems suggest that my new version should work as well.*

The code on that page is significantly different than the code you used. In that code, there's an explicit instruction (`-x`) to ignore the actual shebang line, and to look for one that contains `perl` later in the file (which is also missing from your code).