# Can I do without the shebang line in my Unix Perl scripts?

Tags: perl, unix, shebang

Can I write a Perl program where my first line is not `#!/path/`?

Thank you.

Comment: Unix or Windows (or ??). Windows doesn't care what the first line is, although perl will still honor options on the #! line.

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned it, Unix :)

Comment: Why you would want that ?  What's the problem with the shebang ?

Comment: there is no harm in learning new things :)

Comment: Yes. Take out the shebang line and instead of typing "my_prog" type "perl my_prog". There. Isn't that better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, from `perldoc perlrun` (under the `-S` switch):

```
#!/bin/sh
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
```

See that documentation for the complete story.

Comment: nice! thanks, what is this ${1+"$@"} for? Is it some error evaluation?

Comment: It's equivalent to `"$@"` on modern implementations of the Bourne shell. Older implementations of `sh` need to use that more complex expression.

Comment: If $1 is defined, then expand the parameter to "$@", which is a list of all the parameters, each quoted. If $1 is not defined then nothing is expanded. Was necessary under old shell implementations because just "$@" (with the quotes) would expand to a single argument of an empty string. See http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/bourne_args/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308874/explain-the-deviousness-of-the-perl-preamble

Answer (score 8):

The shebang (`#!`)is only necessary if you want to invoke the script directly at a shell prompt, e.g. `./yourscript`. You can always do `perl yourscript` and skip the shebang.

Answer (score 6):

If your concern is hard-coding a constant path (e.g. #!/usr/bin/perl as opposed to #!/usr/local/bin/perl), then use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

This allows the Perl interpreter to be sought in your PATH, making your scripts a bit more portable (Windows aside).

Answer (score 0):

If you do that then you'll need to invoke Perl explicitly. If that line is there, then the system knows that it is a Perl script so when you make the script executable you can just write ./script